# Axios get request from React to Spring Boot application returns Network Error

Tags: java, reactjs, rest, spring-boot, axios

I have a SpringBoot application with a @Controller that accepts a getRequest to localhost:8080/all and returns JSON. I have entered this domain in the browser and see the returned JSON.

However, when I attempt to hit this url with an Axios get request from my React app (which is running locally), rather than returning the JSON data, it returns the following error:

```
Network Error at createError (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:1634:15) at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:1170:14)
```

I checked Chrome's network tab for the get request and it doesn't return anything for the preview or response, but does indicate:

```
Request URL: https://localhost:8080/all
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

in the Headers section.

Both applications are running locally and when I try a different axios get request (for a different API) it returns the JSON successfully. How can I successfully return JSON from my Spring Boot application?

The React setup for the API call is:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('https://localhost:8080/all')
    .then(function (response) {

      console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {

      console.log(error);
    });
  }
```

And the controller action in the Spring Boot app is:

```
@RestController    
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    UserJDBCDao dao;

    @GetMapping(path="/all")
    public @ResponseBody Iterable<User> getAllUsers() {
        // This returns a JSON or XML with the users
        return dao.findAll();
    }


}
```

Comment: What does your network tab of chrome show?

Comment: i updated with that info.

Comment: what about error log of spring boot application?

Comment: that was it. i had to change https to http

Answer (score 1):

After checking the Spring Boot error log it indicated:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in method name. HTTP method names must be tokens
```

So I changed https to http and the request worked. I'm not sure if this is the most secure way, so someone else might have a better solution.